# Break h2 element's background

Tags: html, css

I have an h2 element inside a div. The div is 150px wide but the h2 might be wider, so the text must break and go to the next line. The problem is that even that the text breaks, the background-color of the h2 element doesn't, and thus the h2 element's background color covers the entire div.

Is there a way I could make the h2's background-color appear only under the text?

Example:  http://codepen.io/anon/pen/azBOLO

**HTML**:

```
<div>
  <h2>This is a long text test</h2>
</div>
```

**CSS**:

```
div {
  background-color: green;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  padding-top: 15px;
}

h2 {
  background-color: red;
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to achieve something like [this](http://codepen.io/hari_shanx/pen/azBOVO)?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I want, indeed!  What other limitations?

Comment: Well, H2 is by default a block element so making it `inline` would for instance make setting a specific width impossible, transforms don't work on inline elements generally. (Pinging @Natsu in case they have more to add).

Comment: What should I use instead of an h2 ?

Comment: Well, if it is just text we can use `span` maybe and apply required styling. It all depends on what other characteristics the text/that block should have.

Comment: Ok, I switched to span (check updated codepen), but the padding isn't correct on the second line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally made it using this trick: http://css-tricks.com/multi-line-padded-text/

EDIT: As suggested, the trick is to set a padding-left on the div, and then create a ::after class on the span that will fill the empty space on the left (same background color, no text).

That way you can achieve padding on a multiline span

Answer (score 3):

Set the `h2` to `display:inline` and `line-height` to `1em` to ensure each line nests with the previous one without gaps.

```css
div {
  background-color: green;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  padding-top: 15px;
}
h2 {
  background-color: red;
  display: inline;
  line-height: 1em;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h2>This is a long text test</h2>

</div>
```